# Launching multiple instances of QGIS (Mac)?

Tags: qgis, mac

Often I need to work on two qgis projects at the same time. How can I launch two separate instances of QGIS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not necessarily specific to QGIS but is a question I often get with QGIS users needing to reference two projects at the same time.

open a terminal window and type:

```
open -n /Applications/QGIS.app
```

Or for QGIS3, open a terminal window and type:

```
open -n /Applications/QGIS3.app
```

this format will work with any application:

open -n /Applications/***Application***.app

Comment: or directly `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS` without open

Comment: This works, but keeps the terminal output active--which one might want, but if you just want to open an instance w/o any additional terminal output, use 'open -n'

Answer (score 1):

You can make an Automator script to launch as many QGIS instances as you want.

Create a new Automator application process.

Add « Run shell script action »

and type this:

> /Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
>
> done

If you stop the running process, QGIS will still run and you'll be able to launch a third, a fourth, etc instance of QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under MacOS 10.15.7 Catalina, opening the app directly in Automator would not create a new instance if QGIS was already running.

This Automator code worked for me: make a new Automator Application, add "Run Shell Script" with options "Shell: /bin/zsh" and "Pass input: as arguments", with this command:

```
open -n -a  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS $argv
```

Save this as "QGIS New Instance.app" in your /Applications folder. This has the advantage that you can drop a file on the Automator Application and have it open in QGIS. Of course, you have to adjust the path to where you keep QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

With an already open instance of QGIS, typing `qgis` into the command line in the terminal opens a subsequent instance of QGIS

Tested on Max M1 with QGIS 3.30.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).